# UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit Updating multiple field

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have multiple textbox with the biding set as explicit

```
Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit, XPath=Columns/Column[1]/@Header}"
```

when i try to update them with with a button:

```
 txtName.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
 txtColumn1.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
 txtColumn2.GetBindingExpression( TextBox.TextProperty ).UpdateSource();
```

The first line of code will update his one and reset the biding of all the texboxes meaning that only the first textbox will update the underlining property.

Any idea of how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "reset the binding"? Why won't all other text boxes be updated as well?  I've tried simple example and it does work...

Comment: It work exactly like as if i called the UpdateTarget() of all other binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all other text boxes are updated because the first text box raised the change notification, you can have some "Update source in progress" flag, and don't raise the Property Change Notification in this case, than the Binding Targets won't get updated, and you'd be able to continue updating the binding sources.